# Cross Referencing Table Value for Another Value to allow Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I look at one table and use it to check another table for data integrity?

I have two SQL Tables.

One that is a person table

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
 ID              INT IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL,
 Firstname       VARCHAR(15),
 Lastname        VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 Birthdate       DATE,
 Gender          VARCHAR(1),
   CHECK ( GENDER IN ('M', 'F')),
 Street          VARCHAR(50),
 City            VARCHAR(15),
 State           VARCHAR(2),
   CHECK (State IN ('FL','GA','PA')),
 Zip             INT,
 Phone           VARCHAR(10),
 Employee        VARCHAR(1),
   CHECK ( Employee IN('Y','N')),
 Member          VARCHAR(1),
   CHECK ( Member IN('Y','N')),
   CHECK (Member IN ('Y') or Employee IN ('Y')),

 CONSTRAINT PERSON_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

And Employee Table

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
 ID               INT NOT NULL,
 Datehired        DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
 Status        VARCHAR(1),
   CHECK ( Status IN ('F','C')),
 Position      VARCHAR(25),
 EmpType       VARCHAR(25),

 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PERSON_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES PERSON);
```

Let's say someone isn't an employee. I can still insert them into the Employee Table.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
 (ID, Status, Position, EmpType)
  VALUES
 ('10000','C','Teaching Classes','Instructor');
```

How Do I prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to have a redundant key:

```
alter table person
    contraint unq_person_id_employee
        unique (id, employee);
```

Then add a computed column to employee:

```
alter table employee add employee as ('Y') persisted;
```

Finally, add the constraint:

```
alter table employee
    add constraint fk_employee_person
        foreign key (id, employee) references person(id, employee);
```

Now, you are guaranteed that only employees are in the `Employee` table.

Comment: Hey I tried what you said and it gave me this error  



Msg 1764, Level 16, State 1, Line 313
Computed Column 'employee' in table 'EMPLOYEE' is invalid for use in 'FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT' because it is not persisted.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 313
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.